# Messed up records - separator inside field content

Tags: python, perl, language-agnostic

I am provided with text files containing data that I need to load into a postgres database.

The files are structured in records (one per line) with fields separated by a tilde (~). Unfortunately it happens that every now and then a field content will include a tilde.

As the files are not tidy CSV, and the tilde's not escaped, this results in records containing too many fields, which cause the database to throw an exception and stop loading.

I know what the record should look like (text, integer, float fields).

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix the overlong records? I code in per but I am happy with suggestions in python, javascript, plain english.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: What about Perl's `Text::CSV` module or Python's `csv` module?

Comment: Are the text fields quoted?  E.g. like this: `"foo"~123~1.25`

Comment: You could do something simple like: `perl -F'~' -lane 'print if @F > 10' input.txt > broken_fields.txt` where "10" is the max number of fields allowed. Then you can examine the broken fields at your leisure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to filter out the corrupted lines with something like:

```
perl -F'~' -lane 'print if @F > 10' input.txt > broken_fields.txt
```

(Assuming your max number of fields is 10). It will give you a short(er) file with suspect lines that you could perhaps inspect manually. This will not be a foolproof filter, it will for example print out allowed fields, such as tildes inside quoted strings. If you want something more exact, you can use `Text::CSV`, but that will present other difficulties when it comes to broken csv data.

There might be a better (and automatic) way to solve this, but without knowing what your input looks like, there is no way to really recommend something.

Comment: I did as you suggested. That led me to identifying the two fields that were the culprits (text fields in the database that gets dumped). Since I have two other fields that MUST contain certain strings, I can now fix the string until those two fields check against a regexp. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what each field is supposed to be, perhaps you could write a regular expression which would match that field type only (ignoring tildes) and capture the match, then replace the original string in the file?